# Server side filtering - Courier, Postfix, Roundcube

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I have a mail server running Postfix, Courier, and Roundcube.  I'm looking to add the ability for a user to assign their own custom mail filters from the web.  I haven't yet found a way I can do this, from what I can tell Roundcube's filter plugin works just like it would on a mail client - that meaning, it has to check the mail before it can filter them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find something that does the Sieve protocol, I think you will have found just what you want. Sieve is a protocol that lets you upload filters to the server and have them applied as the mail is delivered to the users. I have set up Sieve on my server setup (about 2 years ago), but I was using Postfix, Dovecot, and the Sieve plugin for Dovecot. So I'm probably not much direct help, but hopefully it will give you an idea of a direction you could go. I would not be at all surprised if Courier has a Sieve plugin you can set up. Then I guess if you could find a webmail client that lets you set Sieve filters, then you would be all set.

Maybe one of these would be something that would work:

- http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=73
- http://plugins.roundcube.net/packages/johndoh/sieverules
- http://trac.roundcube.net/browser/github/plugins/managesieve/managesieve.php

The one thing that concerns me is that I haven't found anything saying how to set up Courier to do Sieve. When I set up my mail server, it was using Dovecot. I did find something on a mailing list about it not supporting Sieve at the time of that message, but couldn't find anything that said either way if current version of Courier can do Sieve.

Comment: I've found a lot of stuff saying they don't plan to do Sieve.  I would love to use Dovecot but it had issues with Android and my mail client.  It kept putting all of the folders as subfolders of the Inbox, which confused the Android stock mail client, had a lot of trouble with it crashing.

Comment: Turned out the only solution was not not use Courier.

Comment: Hm, we run Dovecot as our main POP/IMAP server for an ISP of about 3,000 customers, and being one of our phone support staff, we didn't have any trouble with Android (or at least not any more than the normal stuff that inevitably happens with all mail clients: misconfigurations, usually by user error).

Comment: yeah it turned out to be my mistakes, so now I have dovecot working perfectly.  Well, almost perfectly, still having issues with SSL certificates but I think I got that solved.

Comment: OK, if you get stuck, feel free to ask questions. I might be able to answer, I've set up Dovecot from scratch before, and have root access to a "professionally" set up (sold as a package) Dovecot install.